# My props value for 'streams' is always undefined

Tags: mongodb, redux, react-redux, react-router, axios

I'm finding that no matter that I do, my value for this.props.streams is always undefined. I have confirmed that the backend API is returning values when queried. Example output:

```
    {
        "welcome": "Livestream service",
        "livestreamURL": "https://",
        "replayURL": "https://",
        "completedURL": "https://",
        "_id": "6027e477fe33c55e8c5eef9c",
        "title": "Service for derping",
        "owner": "Derpface",
        "serviceDate": "2021-02-25T12:00:00.000Z",
        "dateAdded": "2021-02-13T14:38:47.673Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "welcome": "Livestream service",
        "livestreamURL": "https://",
        "replayURL": "https://",
        "completedURL": "https://",
        "_id": "6027e47afe33c55e8c5eef9d",
        "title": "Service for derping",
        "owner": "Derpface",
        "serviceDate": "2021-02-25T12:00:00.000Z",
        "dateAdded": "2021-02-13T14:38:50.749Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to populate the results to props. I have the concerned files below:

**client/src/components/StreamList.js**: (Where the problem is)

```
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getStreams, deleteStream, addStream } from '../actions/streamActions';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class StreamList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getStreams: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    stream: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getStreams();
  }

  onDeleteClick = (_id) => {
    this.props.deleteStream(_id);
  };

  render() {
    const { streams } = this.props.streams;
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
          <>
            <h2>You're logged in.</h2>
            <ListGroup>
              <TransitionGroup className="stream-list">
                {streams.map(({ _id, title }) => (
                  <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                    <ListGroupItem>
                      {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
                        <Button
                          className="remove-btn"
                          color="danger"
                          size="sm"
                          onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
                        >
                          &times;{" "}
                        </Button>
                      ) : null}

                      {title}
                    </ListGroupItem>
                  </CSSTransition>
                ))}
              </TransitionGroup>
            </ListGroup>
          </>
        ) :
          <h2>You must be logged in to see conent</h2>}

      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  stream: state.stream,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getStreams, deleteStream })(StreamList);
```

**/client/src/streamActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_STREAMS, ADD_STREAM, DELETE_STREAM, STREAMS_LOADING } from "./types";
import { tokenConfig } from "./authActions";
import { returnErrors } from "./errorActions";

export const getStreams = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setStreamsLoading());
  axios
    .get("/api/streams")
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_STREAMS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const addStream = (stream) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/streams", stream, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_STREAM,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const deleteStream = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/streams/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_STREAM,
        payload: id,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const setStreamsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: STREAMS_LOADING,
  };
};
```

**/client/stc/reducers**

```
import { GET_STREAMS, ADD_STREAM, DELETE_STREAM, STREAMS_LOADING } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  streams: [],
  loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_STREAMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        streams: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_STREAM:
      return {
        ...state,
        streams: state.streams.filter(stream => stream._id !== action.payload)
      };
    case ADD_STREAM:
      return {
        ...state,
        streams: [action.payload, ...state.streams]
      };
    case STREAMS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**/client/src/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';
// import ShoppingList from './components/ShoppingList';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
// import ItemModal from './components/ItemModal';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { loadUser } from './actions/authActions';

import StreamList from './components/StreamList';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import PassResetForm from './components/auth/PassResetForm';
import UserProfile from './components/auth/UserProfile';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <div className="App">
            <AppNavbar />
            <Container>
              <Route exact={true} path="/api/users/resetpassword/:resetLink" component={PassResetForm} />
              <Route exact={true} path="/api/auth/:user" component={UserProfile} />
              <StreamList />
            </Container>
          </div>
        </Provider>
      </Router>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

**Lastly, /routes/api/streams.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");

// Item model
const Stream = require("../../models/Stream");

// @route GET api/streams
// @desc GET all Streams
// @access  Private

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log('router.get /streams')
  Stream.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then((streams) => res.json(streams));
    // console.log(streams)
});

// @route POST api/streams
// @desc Create an stream
// @access  Private

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newStream = new Stream({
    title: req.body.title,
    owner: req.body.owner,
    serviceDate: new Date(req.body.serviceDate),
  });
  newStream.save().then((stream) => res.json(stream));
});



module.exports = router;
```

I appreciate any help anyone can offer. Sorry for the walls of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to be kicking yourself because this is just a typo!  Your component is receiving `this.props.stream` (singular) not `this.props.streams` (plural).

Comment: I really am, because it seems this was exactly it. Thank you Linda for giving me a second set of eyes and finding this. :)